# Node.js и post запрос включающий cookie

Tags: node.js, post, cookie

Пытаюсь в node.js отправить пост запрос с куками.

```
    var cookiejar = rp.jar();
    cookiejar.setCookie(user.cookie);
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://test.ru',
        jar: cookiejar,
        formData: {param1: "1", param2: 2},
    };

    rp(options)
    .then(function (body) {
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
    });
```

При отправке данного post запроса скрипт крэшится. Помогите, понять причину и исправить.

Comment: что пишет в консоли?

Comment: В ветку catch не заходит, очевидно надо обернуть еще повыше на уровень.